# I need a java stomp client library that works with ssl

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying several stomp libraries for java (gozirra, stompj, activemq). 
All these libraries have poor documentation, such as having only one example, and I have a serious problem:

I need SSL support.

The stomp+ssl protocol exists and is supported by activemq but I am not able to find a Java client that supports it.

Comment: Just curious... if client is Java, why using Stomp?

Comment: The application is an Android application and I cannot use JMS or openwire (as far as I know).

Comment: Have you found a working stomp+ssl client?

Comment: Yes, http://stomp.fusesource.org/

Comment: mgiammarco, link cannot be opened. Can you update?

Comment: https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With library from activemq do it this way :

```
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
            "/home/foo/.keystore/client.ks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeme");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
            "/home/foo/.keystore/client.ts");

    StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory
            .getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("127.0.0.1",
            61612);
    connection.open(sslsocket);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found [this forum discussion](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMQ-for-Android-td3220245.html) about JMS on Android, which references [the experimental Stomp API](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html#Stomp-JavaAPI) included in ActiveMQ 5.2 and greater (example copied below)

Also mentioned is that the [REST API](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) might be a better fit for mobile devices, allowing state to be maintained purely at the broker.

```
StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
connection.open("localhost", 61613);

connection.connect("system", "manager");
StompFrame connect = connection.receive();
if (!connect.getAction().equals(Stomp.Responses.CONNECTED)) {
    throw new Exception ("Not connected");
}

connection.begin("tx1");
connection.send("/queue/test", "message1", "tx1", null);
connection.send("/queue/test", "message2", "tx1", null);
connection.commit("tx1");

connection.subscribe("/queue/test", Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT);

connection.begin("tx2");

StompFrame message = connection.receive();
System.out.println(message.getBody());
connection.ack(message, "tx2");

message = connection.receive();
System.out.println(message.getBody());
connection.ack(message, "tx2");

connection.commit("tx2");
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank but I have found (and tried ) at least three java stomp client and they work. Unfortunately no SSL and I badly need it. Thanks for the REST idea but I will try after I fail all attempts with stomp.

Comment: Are you sure your SSL certs are working?  Have you had success with any STOMP+SSL clients (non-Java)?

Comment: I can say that I have successfully configured the activemq server to use stomp+ssl protocol. Tried with telnet it starts an ssl negotiation. I have not yet tried with any client (java or non java).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it works on Android but worth a try is the [FuseSource StompJMS](https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms) client available on [Github](https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms).  It uses the hwatdispatch library which has both standard TCP and SSL transports built in.  Worth a shot anyway.

Comment: I have tried it following your suggestion, I have seen it supports ssl, but due to the fact that there is no example and no docs, I am not able to configure the keystore and so the ssl connection fails. Any idea?

Comment: Ok I confirm that FuseSource Stomp implementation works with ssl but the documentation is lacking...

Comment: It has a horrible license - you would need to make your application source code freely available if you use this, which means it is no use commercially.